# C# serialisation problem

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

This is a class in a c# application:

```
[Serializable()] 
public class AAA
{
    private List<AAA> arr;
    private AAA parentA;

    public List<AAA> Arr
    {
        get { return arr; }
        set { arr = value; }
    }

    public AAA ParentA        
    {
        get { return parentA; }
        set { parentA = value; }
    }
 }
```

when I try to serialize this class by XMLSerializer and the list "arr" or  "parentA" are containing a value the serialization fail to write the XML.

Can you please uggest a way how to resolve it?

Please attach code example.

Note: I must use XMLSerializer, Not any other serializer.

10x

Comment: Hi, what error are you getting when you try to serialize? you might need to add the [Serializable] attribute to the class definition

Comment: XML Serializers are usually not particullary happy about circular references...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to the class attribute

> [XmlInclude(typeof(AAA))] public class
>   AAA

and public field like

> [XmlArray("AAAarray")]
>   [XmlArrayItem("Param", typeof(AAA))]
>   public IList arr { get; set; }

Answer (score 2):

Missing attribute? And the variable might have to be public.

```
[Serializable()]
public class AAA {
    public List<AAA> arr;
    public AAA parentA;
}
```

Comment: `Serializable` doesn't affect XML serializtion.